# Directive is not updating after updated value is sent from a service

Tags: angularjs

I am facing a problem with showing a counter value inside a directive.

I am working on an cart application where I have a header directive which is loading only once, when the app loads. I have list of products with 2 links/buttons for adding in wishlist and adding in cart.

**Scenario:**

When I am adding a product in wishlist, I am getting that product object from my controller and sending it in a service where I am pushing that object in a service wishlist array. Then I am running a loop to to count the number of objects inside the wishlist array and caching it in a service variable (I am not using $rootScope). I am using another service function to return this updated wishlist array count. Inside the directive I am using this service function to get the updated count.

**Problem:**

The wishlist array count is updating each time I am adding a product inside the wishlist array. But it is not showing the updated value in the view.

Comment: Can you attach some code which you think might be the culprit?

Comment: @Icycool no code here is culprit. There is some problem in logic or approach. Could you help me out on how to update the view of the directive from service

Answer (score 0):

See if you want use service then use its reference variable as below
[Jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/1evf3sjn/)

*js Code*

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, myservice) {
    $scope.data = myservice.data;
    $scope.add = function() {
      myservice.add('test');
    }
  });

  app.controller('ctrl2', function($scope, myservice) {
    $scope.cart = myservice;
  });

  app.directive('myDir', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      template: '<span>my dir Count {{cart.data.length}}</span>'
    }
  });

  app.directive('myDir1', function(myservice) {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      template: '<span>my dir1 Count {{data.get().length}}</span>',
      scope: {},
      link: function(scope) {
        scope.data = myservice;
      }
    }
  });

  app.service('myservice', function() {
    this.data = [];
    this.add = function(item) {
      this.data.push(item);
    };
    this.get = function() {
      return this.data;
    };
    return this;
  });
```

*HTML code*

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>
  <div ng-controller='ctrl'>
    CTRL
    <button ng-click='add()'>
      Add to wishlist
    </button>
    Data :{{data}}
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div ng-controller='ctrl2'>
    Count {{cart.data.length}}
    <br> Count {{cart.get().length}}
  </div>
</div>
```

This way you can get service data any where in app

Comment: Thank you for the response but my main concern is showing my updated data in my view which is a directive.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it.